# Storing approximate dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I am creating a database that will have several tables requiring the ability to store approximate dates. For example, there will be dates of birth where the full date is known, some where only the month and year is known, some where only the year is known and some where an estimated year is known.
I am trying to think of best set-up for this but cannot think of a better way than having four separate columns, nullable 'day' and 'month', 'year' and 'estimated' (true/false).
is there a better way of doing this, bearing in mind that I would want to filter or search by the date?
Thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: go ahead and do that. And all the bizarre queries and duped up data

Comment: You don't need a `estimated` column if one of the other columns is NULL

Comment: Drew - I am fully aware that my idea is not the best which is why I am asking advice. Not sure what the need for your sarcastic response is?

Comment: juergen d - the only time I would use the estimated column is when no exact details are known but the year is believed to be a specific year. If the month and day are null, this is the only way I can think of to specify whether the given year is exact or estimated.

Comment: If you are speaking to people, learn the use of the @ sign in front of their name so they get pinged and get back to see the interesting questions

Comment: Not sure why you are upset at me to say that. A little over the top. To me your idea is crazy about dates. If it is something you want to pursue, go for it and let us know.